# Connect to webservice with certificate from java

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, certificate

I am connecting to a webservice from a java program.
The webservice requires a certificate in order to give me back any data.
I have not managed to set up the certificate connection with my java code.
Instead I have used something called Stunnel which simply creates a connection to the host with the certificate.
Now I want to remove the stunnel and do everything from java. Surely this must be possible?

This is the config for the stunnel.

```
cert = /etc/stunnel/client.pem
options = NO_SSLv2

[https]
client = yes
accept = 8083
sni = www.xxx.se
connect = www.xxx.se:443
```

And in order to start the tunnel I need to provide a password connected to the certificate so this will also be needed in the code.

My current code.

```
 URL url = new URL(wsdlURL);            
 QName qname =  new QName("urn:ws.fps.xxx.com/supportToolSupport",       "SupportToolSupportService");      
 javax.xml.ws.Service = javax.xml.ws.Service.create(url, qname);        
 SupportToolSupport support = service.getPort(SupportToolSupport.class);    
 List<Company> companies =  support.supportToolGetCompanies("");
```

Any idea what code to do before this code to replace the stunnel?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the class `SupportToolSupport` is pojo generated from the WSDL. When you call `SupportToolSupport.supportToolGetCompanies()` that pojo is actually making the connection. By default it will use your JVM's certificate stores, both the Keystore and TrustStore.  The Keystore is usually called keyStore.jks and the TrustStore is usually called cacerts(.jks).  These are usually found in < java JRE install directory >/lib/security.  You can manage how the JVM accesses the certificate stores programmatically, but if possible it is easier to set up the environment. You can force the JVM to use a specific keystore, alias, and password when calling java by passing these variables to java:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="path to keyStore.jks"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType="JKS"
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="changeit"
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="path to cacerts"
```

For example command line:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="path to keyStore.jks" ... -cp <class path> class.to.run
```

For Eclipse copy and paste the lines above into the **VM Arguments** box of the **Arguments Tab** within the run configurations.
Run -> Run Configurations -> find your configuration -> Select Arguments Tab

Comment: OK Thank you for htis response.
I have tried things like:
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "c:\\client.p12");

But never got this to work.
Maybe one of the files were wrong, or the filepaths or something.
I have a jks fwhich should be the same as the pem file that works.
And I guess the password should be the same then too.
But How do I create a truststore that works?
Do I need a truststore? I want it to trust everything on my side, is there a simpler way to do it then?

Comment: You almost always need a truststore - that is how your JVM knows to "trust" the site you are connecting to. It can get complicated with Certificate Authorites (CA)'s but the easiest thing to do is add the public certificate of the site you are connecting to into your truststore. Then make sure your JVM is using that truststore. Yes, the default password for truststore and keystore is usually 'changeit'. If you create your own cert stores you can set it yourself. You can use keytool, which comes with a JDK, to manage these cert stores.

Comment: Also, you might be able to use your certificate/key file (i.e. the p12 file) as your keystore, but you have to set the keyStoreType property to pkcs12 instead of the default JKS.  I would not do that though, instead I'd import the p12 into keyStore.jks using the keytool utility. It'd be something like: `keytool -importcert -keystore keyStore.jks -storepass changeit -file client.p12 -alias myClient` - [Docs on keytool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html)

Comment: OK been trying to google this but find it very hard.
The keystore and password I think I have. I will use a jks file.

The cacerts however I find harder. Should I copy the cacerts file from my java Java\jre6\lib\security and then somehow add this same jks file into this cacerts file and then use this cacert?

Also if I use the System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "c:/client.jks"); approach in the code instead of  setting the environment(Im not sure how).
How should I write the filepath? I have seen both c:/ and c:\\
Can I check if the property is set with an actual file somehow?

Comment: OK have a cacerts-file now that I believe includes the client.pem file. Have tried this: System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "c:/client.jks"); System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "xxx"); System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS"); System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "c:/cacerts"); System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit"); as well as changing the paths to c:\\client.jks. Neither of this worked. Unfortunatelly there is no error if the service dont get the cert it responds with empty list

Comment: Is there a simple way to see if any files are even added to the properties? Do I need to set trustStoreType? If so what type is the default cacert file? How do I try and set this as jvm-variables instead of doing it in the code like I do now? I currently have this file in a eclipse project and run it by right click - run as java application. Do i set these Djavax parameters in eclipse somewhere or in my java folder? I have no clue. Thanks a lot for all help!

Comment: I'm new to contributing to stackoverflow, so not sure how to proceed - but - See my edits to my original response for how to set these in the JVM arguments when running through Eclipse - use path like "C:\path\to\file".  This way and using `System.setProperty(...)` in the code both work the same. **But in the code** the path must be "C://path/to/file". Verify your keystore and truststore have the appropriate certificates installed using the `keytool -list ...` commands. What error are you getting - SSL Handshake errors are very obvious.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76661/discussion-between-vic-and-johannes).

Comment: OK thank you.
Unfortunately I get no errors, when the server feels I am not using the certificate it just returns an empty array.
Should it work to use the client.jks as both keystore and truststore if I only use this cert? Or do I have to place this client.jks in a cacerts-file for the truststore?